# WriteFile function C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Im trying to use the WriteFile function. Ive been working off this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900134.aspx

Here the buffer that is passed to WriteFile is filled from ReadFile. But I dont want to do it that way. I just want to write a string like "Example text testing WriteFile" or something. But im not sure what values the parameters should have. Ive tried looking around on google but couldnt find anything. Anyone know how i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  __in         HANDLE hFile,
  __in         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  __inout_opt  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

- The first argument is the handle to the file.
- The second argument is a pointer to the data you want to write. In your case it's the string.
- The third argument is the length of the data you want to write. In your case it will be something like `strlen(str)`.
- The fourth argument is a pointer to a `DWORD` variable that will receive the number of bytes actually written.
- The fifth and last parameter can be NULL for now.

You use it like this:

```
char str[] = "Example text testing WriteFile";
DWORD bytesWritten;

WriteFile(fileHandle, str, strlen(str), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

If `WriteFile` returns `FALSE` then there was an error. Use the `GetLastError` function to find out the error code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of writing a string:

(`hOutFile` here is an open file handle from a call to `CreateFile`):

```
{
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    char Str[] = "Example text testing WriteFile";
    WriteFile( hOutFile, Str, strlen(Str), &dwBytesWritten, NULL );
}
```

EDIT: Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function definition for what each parameter does.